# Django.Подключение liqpay

Tags: python, django

Доброго времени суток) Начинаю делать интернет магазин в рамках обучения Django.Возник вопрос как подключить систему оплаты к примеру liqpay.Подскажите в каком направлении смотреть или какая технология этого процесса. Материала крайне мало(